# Exponentially weighted moving standard deviation (EWMSD) in q/kdb+

Tags: kdb

Since it's better ex-ante predictor of volatility than simple standard deviation, I've attempted to write *exponentially weighted moving standard deviation* function in `q` language using this [incremental definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponentially_weighted_moving_variance_and_standard_deviation).

I got inspired by incremental implementation of `ema` function in `q/k`.

```
q) ema
k){(*y)(1f-x)\x*y}
```

Interesting part above is  that `{x y\z}` is shorthand for `{{z+y*x}\[x;y;z]}`.

Here is my stab, however it scans (`\`) the input vector `y` twice:

```
q) .q.emdev:{sqrt 0f (1f-x)\0f^(1f-x)*x*d*d:y-prev ema[x;y]}
q) (1%3) emdev 1,10#0
0 0.4714045 0.496904 0.4566233 0.3981362 0.3381504 0.2829914 0.2347385 0.1936388 0.1591718 0.1305404
```

The core recursion formula (as per the referenced paper above) used:

[image]

Assuming this is correct, has anyone come up with more efficient implementation?

Answer (score 1):

I tried implementing it so that it only scans the input vector once using the incremental formula and returning the next EMA and EMVAR in each loop using only the previous value of each and achieved the same result as you.

```
myemdev:{sqrt (flip {((1f-x)*y[0]+x*d*d;y[1]+x*d:z-y[1])}[x]\[(0;first y);y]) 0}
q)myemdev[(1%3);1,10#0]
0 0.4714045 0.496904 0.4566233 0.3981362 0.3381504 0.2829914 0.2347385 0.1936388 0.1591718 0.1305404
```

But despite the fact that it only loops over the input once, this method takes considerably longer than yours.

```
q)\t {sqrt 0f (1f-x)\0f^(1f-x)*x*d*d:y-prev ema[x;y]}[1%3;1,100000#0]
4
q)\t {sqrt (flip {((1f-x)*y[0]+x*d*d;y[1]+x*d:z-y[1])}[x]\[(0;first y);y]) 0}[1%3;1,100000#0]
189
q)\t ema[1%3;100000#0]
1
q)\t {{z+(1f-x)*y}[x]\[first y;y*x]}[1%3;1,100000#0]
57
```

Looking at these two functions which give identical results, it is clear that a method in the form `{x y\z}` is much quicker than the same function written out as a lambda, although I am not sure of implementation of the optimisation under the hood.

```
q)\t {(1)(1+x)\(x*y)}[0.005;1,1000000#0]
15
q)\t {{z+x*(1+y)}\[1;x;(x*y)]}[0.005;1,1000000#0]
711
```

Although your method uses two scans, both are of the form `{x y\z}` and so from my perspective are very efficient. The benefit of only doing one scan over the input using the pure incremental method is outweighed by the inability to put it into this more efficient form, as `(1f-x;1f)*y` in the rearranged method here: `{sqrt (flip {(1f-x;1f)*y+x*(d,1f)*d:z-y[1]}[x]\[(0;first y);y]) 0}` cannot be pre-computed as we do not have all the EMA values available to us (they are calculated each loop as needed).

I will continue to look for improvements in both methods and I would be interested to see if anybody could beat your method in terms of efficiency

Comment: thank you, indeed, reading listbox forum, back in 2013 they decided to make ``{z+y*x}\`` a builtin C level function as it's a common scalar problem